# Global Workflow for document approval apply all libraries - will this work?

Tags: workflow, document, approval-process

I've searched around and I think I understand Global Workflows but would like to know if this would work before I start developing it since it will take me a few hours.

What I have is a site with 36 subsites each about 20 document libraries.
I want to set up a Document Approval workflow that would be attached to the base document type and (hopefully) work on all the libraries for new/modified documents.

I'll need to pass the library name and document id to the workflow for email routing.

Can Global Workflows do this or should I look for another option??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a designer workflow associated with content type. In your case

> Document Content type

This will be easy to imppliment.